# SqlMetal scripting and capitalization

Tags: sqlmetal

When I run SqlMetal it generates all views and functions with a capital letter.
Is their a way to make it generate it in whatever case is in the database?

When I use the UI to build the DBML and CS file it handles this properly, however when I script it SqlMetal seems to make them upper case.

This isn't a huge deal however it makes me wonder if their are other subtle changes I don't know about or if I'm simply doing something stupid.

Here is what I'm doing, if it helps:

```
SqlMetal.exe /conn:"Data Source=server1\developer2008;Initial Catalog=Dingo;Integrated Security=true" /views /functions /sprocs /pluralize /language:csharp /namespace:"Foo_Api" /context:"DataClassesFooDataContext" /dbml:"foo.dbml"

SqlMetal.exe /code:"foo.designer.cs" "foo.dbml"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you perform a transform (it is XML) on foo.dbml between getting the DB schema and generating the code?